# WordPress dashboard is slooow. Front end is fast

Tags: dashboard, performance

Every aspect of my dashboard is slow--it can take 30-60 seconds to get a list of pages, or to updated a post. Yet, the front end is fast.

I checked all the plugins--no problem there. I deactivated all the features of JetPack--no problem there.

I tried different browsers--no problem there.

I checked with my ISP and they confirmed there was no down time.

This problem is ongoing.

What makes WordPress dashboard slow and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this link:
[Wordpress Support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-back-end-slowfront-end-good)

It suggests these 7 steps about half way down:

> 1. Manually run /wp-admin/upgrade.php (visit it in your browser).
> 2. Try decativating all plugins. If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.
> 3. Try switching to the Twenty Ten theme to rule-out a theme-specific issue.
> 4. Download WordPress again and delete then replace your copies of the /wp-admin/ and /wp-includes/ directories with fresh copies from the download.
> 5. Access your WordPress database via phpMyAdmin (most hosting providers offer this in their control panel), check all of the tables, and choose "Optimize tables" from the pull-down menu.
> 6. Try installing the Memory Bump plugin.
> 7. If nothing else works, try these methods to increase PHP's memory allocation:
>
>    1. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini
>         If your line shows 32M try 64M:
>         memory_limit = 64M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (64MB)
>    2. If you don't have access to PHP.ini try adding this to an .htaccess file:
>         php_value memory_limit 64M
>    3. Try adding this line to your wp-config.php file:
>         Increasing memory allocated to PHP
>         define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
>    4. Talk to your host.

Comment: /wp-admin/upgrade.php was the solution - I'm running multisite, so I had to do it on all the subsites (subdomain based) and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you, unfrev....You saved my day....My WordPress MU dashboard pages were barely working after an upgrade to 4.3.1, until I ran wp-admin/upgrade.php in the browser!